# Find out which app sent an intent to open Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store, miui, intents

My Android phone (MIUI v9) recently seems to open up Google Play (to a specific app detail page) randomly (a few times a day), which might indicate the presence of some adware.

As I understand, to make this happen, an app has to send an Intent with a URI of `market://...`.  I don't know which app is doing this, and I would like to find out, so I can get rid of it.

Theres an app called [Internal Broadcasts Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lt.andro.broadcastlogger&hl=en) on Google Play that logs Intents, but it doesn't tell me which app sent the Intent.  Also, it does not provide any way to filter the list of Intents, which makes it very difficult to find a specific Intent that only happens a few times a day.

Is there any way to find the sender of an Intent, or any other way from Google Play to tell which app launched it?

Comment: Worth a try, especially if you know exactly *when* the intent was sent: `adb logcat -v time`, then check the entries around the time logged by the *Internal Broadcasts Monitor*.